# Number format in French

Tags: php, laravel-5, number-formatting, french

I'm tring to change the number format of my result in my view but i have a problem.

It's shows me **A non well formed numeric value encountered**

My code below

```
<td style="font-size:60%">
<?php
$val = $indemnite->indemnite;

 // Notation française
$resultat = number_format($val, 2, ',', ' ');
// Résultat : 1 234,56
echo $resultat ;
?>
</td>
```

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Comment: This means `$indemnite->indemnite` (and therefore `$val`) is not numeric (and could not be converted to a number either).

Comment: Exactly Jeto, I had a space in my values. You find the solution. Thanks you so much